# Can bind() ever return EINPROGRESS in real systems?

Tags: sockets, posix

According to POSIX, if you call `bind` on a non-blocking socket, it's allowed to return `EINPROGRESS` and complete asynchronously. ([Reference.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/bind.html))

I checked the source to libuv and Twisted, and as far as I can tell they both call `bind` on non-blocking sockets without doing anything to handle this error. Neither the Linux or FreeBSD `bind(2)` man pages mention this as a possible outcome.

Does this actually happen on any real systems? And if so, how do you get notified when the `bind` has completed?

Comment: The [same Reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/bind.html) also says: "*When the assignment has been performed asynchronously, `pselect()`, `select()`, and `poll()` shall indicate that the file descriptor for the socket is ready for reading and writing.*"  So just like any other asynchronous socket operation, you have to poll the socket state to know when the operation has been completed.  You should keep track to know if you are waiting on `bind()` vs `recv()` vs `send()`, etc.

Comment: `bind()` doesn't do anything on the network, so it has nothing to block *for.* I suspect this is all editorial error. @RemyLebeau That doesn't actually make sense. A socket which has only been bound is *never* ready for I/O. You have to call `listen()` or `connect()` on it for it to be eligible for that.

Comment: I fact I think `listen()` is also described as a blocking call, but nobody programs for that either.

Comment: I don't see anything about `listen` completing asynchronously. And it looks like for `bind` this was an intentional change: [see here](https://www.opengroup.org/austin/aardvark/latest/xshbug2.txt) and search for ud-bind-async. So it sounds like it should never happen for IPv4/6, but in theory for some other protocols it could. I'd still be interested to know if any such implementations have ever been deployed and what their behavior is if so.